# How to execute python files separately as a python script?

Tags: python

What I want to do is have a python script (that's a python IRC bot) that can run another python script in the background/separately.

I could do something like this:

```
#irc codey stuff here...
if x == y:
    os.system('s%\stuff.py') % path
```

But this would stop **main.py** and it then runs **stuff.py** (in 1 command prompt) which I don't want to do.
So what I am trying to make this script do is when the IRC bot picks up a command via IRC, I want it to run stuff.py separately, like double clicking on **stuff.py** and having **main.py** and **stuff.py** running at the same time.

If there is a separate way of doing this in windows/linux, please, can you show both?

Comment: You're saying you want two different shell prompts, one that runs stuff.py and one that runs main.py?

Comment: @elvis, yea, thays what i want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To spawn a background process, use the Popen class in the subprocess module.

Example:

```
from subprocess import Popen
process = Popen(['firefox', '-P', '-no-remote'])
```

After this `process` is a process object that can be used to kill the process, wait for it to finish, communicate with it etc. If you just want to spawn the process and forget about it, you don't need to keep the return value from Popen.

Answer (score 1):

The [subprocess](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/subprocess/) library may be useful. It allows for background processes and handles some of the forking and child management for you.

Answer (score 1):

To open up a separate shell in windows, you could do:

```
os.system('cmd.exe /c stuff.py')
```

Or, as others have pointed out, use the `subprocess` module. Actually, `subprocess` should be a reflex - the tool you grab for, when starting other processes...

Answer (score 0):

To execute CPU-intensive Python code in the background you could use [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from stuff import some_function

if __name__=='__main__':
   pool = mp.Pool()
   # ...
   if x == y:
      pool.apply_async(some_function, args) # use mp.Queue or 
                                            # save returned value or 
                                            # specify a callback
                                            # to get deferred result from the function
```

If you go the `subprocess` route then to use the same Python launcher as the current script you could try [`sys.executable`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.executable):

```
import os
import sys
from subprocess import Popen

p = Popen([sys.executable, os.path.join(path, 'stuff.py')])
```